# PHP OOP with Facade Pattern who should print html?

Tags: php, html, oop, facade

i am developing an application with the Facade Pattern in PHP ( i was asked for this particular pattern ), after developing the classes and understanding how facade manages the complexity i came across a doubt:
Who should print my HTML code?
I mean the facade should use the objects which should not be directly accessed from the pages as i have understood ( i may be wrong here... ) so if the facade is the only one to have access to my objects should it be the facade to print the HTML code?
If i have for example a list of Orders ( order is one of my classes which cointains other objects ) and i need to print a table to show all the orders, should i make a method for the facade so that i can do something like

```html
class facade{

//....other stuff....

  function printOrders(){
    foreach($orders as $oneorder){
      echo "<tr><td>$oneorder->getPrice()</td><td>$oneorder->getDescription()</td></tr>
    }
  }


//....other stuff....

}
```

or should i make use of the orders ( array of Order class instances ) in the pages directly?

Comment: Your facade unless its wrapping some kind of view model should not be outputting HTML. This should be the responsibility of your view and its helpers/models which should be seprate from you business/data models though it may consume those (or thier facades). At least as i understand it from what you have noted here.

Comment: I'm new to using it, so excuse me if i haven't understood what you said correctly, what you mean is that the right way to do this would be to implement a view class that will interact with the objects and print them, right?

Comment: You do not use a design pattern because you are asked to, you use one to solve a specific issue. Is it a school project? What complex sub-system are you trying to hide behind a Facade?

Comment: Well if you are doing proper OOP you should almost certainly have your view separated from your Data and/or Domain models which is what the Facade is wrapping. So by implication you would have some kind of View engine. But to second what plalx said you should use a facade because there is  a need. The pattern is meant to provide a simplified interface to a group of interconnected systems. If thats not your use case then it is debatable whether you should even be using it or not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: Thank you all for your help, first of all this project is an assignment for my college teacher who requested me a facade pattern application, after your advices it now seems to make much more sense! I have now a view layer which communicates with my facade to retrieve and print the objects i need to echo. Most of alla, the application now seems much more modular so i thank you both very much!